# unable to deploy on chalice with pulp python library

Tags: python, pulp, chalice

I'm running ***amazon ec2 instance***. Have created a chalice project. So far, have installed pulp into the project folder using `pip -install pulp -t /home/test/project/vendor/`

When doing chalice deploy, I get error:

```
return json.dumps(serialized_body).encode(self.DEFAULT_ENCODING)
MemoryError
```

When deleting the pulp from the vendor folder, chalice deploy works fine. please help.

Comment: Did you test the pulp installation? From EC2 Python IDE, can you try `>>> import pulp` and then  `>>> pulp.pulpTestAll().` That way you can start to rule out possible causes.

Comment: In which instance type are you running this? `MemoryError` means the Python interpreter ran out of memory (RAM). Try running in an instance with more RAM and let us know.